# How to insert into a table with ONLY an Auto-Increment column

Tags: .net-core, entity-framework-core

I have a table the only has an Id column in SQL.  It is an Auto-Increment column.  It is used to keep track of a booking number sequence to be sent to an outside system.  In SQL I use this to insert a new record:

```
insert into bookingnumbers default values
```

I would like to use entity framework and get the Next available Id.  I have tried this:

```
    private async Task<long> GetNextBookingNumberAsync()
    {
        BookingNumbers bookingNumber = default;
        GhanemContext.BookingNumbers.Add(bookingNumber);
        await GhanemContext.SaveChangesAsync();
        return bookingNumber.Id;
    }
```

However, booking number is just null and I get:

```
ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null. Parameter name: entity
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Instead of `bookingNumber = default` use `bookingNumber = new BookingNumber()`. It doesn't matter if it only has `Id` column or not.

Comment: So simple, Can't believe I did not try that... I feel stupid... Thanks for the help!